# Select max 2 records from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this in item table

```
Tabel siswa                          Tabel jurusan             Tabel Penjurusan
id_siswa nama nilai tes id_jurusan   id_jurusan   nama         id id_siswa id_jurusan option ket
1         A     6         01           01          Sipil       1    1        01         1    lULUS
2         B     7         02           02          Mesin       2    1        02         2    TIDAK LULUS
3         C     8         01           03          Sastra      3    1        03         3    TIDAK LULUS
4         D     6         03                                   4    2        01         1    LULUS
5         E     7         02                                   5    2        02         2    TIDAK LULUS


                                                          6    2        03         3    TIDAK LULUS
```

AND i have query like this

```
SELECT nama_jurusan, nama_lengkap AS NAMA, nilai_tes FROM siswa, penjurusan, jurusan
WHERE siswa.kode = penjurusan.kode AND jurusan.id_jurusan = penjurusan.id_jurusan AND penjurusan.keterangan = "LULUS"
GROUP BY nama_jurusan
ORDER BY nilai_tes ASC
```

and the result must be

nama   nama_jurusan nilai_tes

B                                           Sipil        7

A       Sipil        6

but my query can not select max 2 record and only max 1 record.

can you help me how to solve this problem?

thank you.

Comment: i want to select top 2 result based on a spesific field. the result must be
nama  nama_jurusan nilai_tes
B     Sipil         7
B     Sipil         6

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: I recommend you ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operations, and use the JOIN keyword instead; and relocate the join predicates to an `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause, no matter which database you are using. Also, best practice is to qualify all column references with a table name or a table alias.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't want to be using `GROUP BY`, but rather `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT nama_jurusan, nama_lengkap AS NAMA, nilai_tes 
FROM siswa s 
    INNER JOIN penjurusan p ON s.kode = p.kode 
    INNER JOIN jurusan j ON j.id_jurusan = p.id_jurusan 
WHERE p.keterangan = 'LULUS'
ORDER BY nilai_tes ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Depending on your desired results, you may need to use `DESC` instead of `ASC`.  Also, please note the use of the `INNER JOIN` syntax.

---

Given your comments, you want two records per group.  You can create your own `row_number` with `IF` and then use it to get the top two per group.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT nama_jurusan, 
           nama_lengkap AS NAMA, 
           nilai_tes, 
           @rn:=IF(@prevjurusan=nama_jurusan,@rn+1,1) as rn, 
           @prevjurusan:=nama_jurusuan
    FROM siswa s 
        INNER JOIN penjurusan p ON s.kode = p.kode 
        INNER JOIN jurusan j ON j.id_jurusan = p.id_jurusan 
        CROSS JOIN (select @rn:= 0, @prevjurusan:='') t
    WHERE p.keterangan = 'LULUS'
    ORDER BY nama_jurusan, nilai_tes 
) y
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Comment: the relust is not perhaps. i want to make relust "sipil" have 2 max, "mesin" have 2 max and "sastra" have 2 max. but with your code "sipil" only have 1 Max. how about this?

Comment: @user3695958 -- I'm sorry, I just don't understand your question... Please build a fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) and show us what you're getting and what you're expecting.

Comment: maybe my problem same like this, but i dont know how to implementation in my table

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a6c137b-a506-4ebe-a96a-e9fac2f3c859/select-max-2-records-from-table?forum=transactsql

Comment: @user3695958 -- see if those edits don't help.  Basically, you need to establish a `row_number` to get 2 results per group.

Comment: wouldn't you need to order by `nama_jurusan` first and `nilai_tes` second?

Comment: @FuzzyTree - you are correct.  That would ensure the correct groupings.  Having a hard time with those column names...

Comment: oke thank you, but still error "Unknown column 'rn' in 'where clause'". how?

Comment: @user3695958 -- see edits, I gave the column an alias.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an AND operator with Value ="LULUS", and there is only one of that !
change your condition

Comment: but i want to select value max 2 in student have value="LULUS"